# Changing UILabel Y position in TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I've a `UITableViewController` and I placed a `UILabel` beneath the tableview in interface builder.  However, I can't seem to control the actual Y position of the label.  There's a big gap between the tableview and the label that I'd like to reduce by moving the label up a  bit.  I tried moving the labels `origin.y` programmatically but it remains in the same spot.

Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What type of ui style applied. Ex auto resize, auto layout

Comment: `UITableViewController` is not a good candidate for this. `UITableViewController's` `self.view` is a `UITableView` which would like to manage all of its subviews itself. It is better to use just a generic `UIViewController` add a `UITableView` and `UILabel` to it's `self.view` which is a generic `UIView`.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P I believe its auto layout.  But you can't set any constraints.

Comment: @beyowulf the lyft app does this when you want to change your email or other settings.  Looks like its `UITableViewController` grouped style.

Comment: One possible way change to auto resize then change and check the y value

Comment: I'm not sure what the table view style has to do with it. You can change the style of a UITableView that you drag into UIViewController. You should look at the document outline of your UITableViewController, and you will notice that self.view is actually self.tableView, so when you drag a UILabel onto it, that is like saying `self.tableView.addSubview(label)` which will not provide good results. You want your label and table view to be siblings not parent/child.

Comment: @beyowulf I originally was using a UIViewController and inserting a tableview, but I couldn't get the same appearance as the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it at the bottom of the table view, you can just add it as the `tableFooterView`. For example:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let footerLabel = UILabel()
        footerLabel.text = "Some Text"
        footerLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        footerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        footerLabel.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerLabel
    }
```

You can use either a table view added to a `UIViewController` or a `UITableViewController`.

The `tableFooterView` directly abuts the section footer for the last section of the table view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.1 // adjust this value to determine how close the label is to the last table view cell. Don't return 0 unless you want the default value for grouped style table views
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think the end result of your answer is the same as my original problem.  I'm assuming its not possible to reduce the spacing between the label and the bottom cell.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm still not sure what you want though.

Comment: `heightForFooterInSection` did the job!